# How to reduce the number of repetitions for formatting many tables?

Tags: excel, vba, optimization, formatting

I have a nice table with a VBA code that fills it and format it automatically (I have been working on this quite a while).

It's very nice, fast, working good, but when I look at the code, there is tens and tens of lines just concerning the formatting of cells...

Is there a way to optimize this, to make it more bearable to human eye/brain?

I let you see :

```vb
Application.DisplayAlerts = False                                           'Deactivate the alerts in case the cell is filled
    With Range("A" & PosStartLine + (TPICode * 3) - 3 & ":A" & PosStartLine + (TPICode * 3) - 1)
        .Select
        .Value = FullTPICode
        .Interior.Color = RGB(220, 230, 241)
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Font.Size = 11
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Merge       'Merging the 3 cells
        .EntireRow.Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlMedium
        .EntireRow.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Writes down the details on the next column (as we're there... why not?)
    With Worksheets(RealData).Range("B" & PosStartLine + (TPICode * 3) - 3)
        .Select
        .Value = "Nb cars done"
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Interior.Color = RGB(216, 228, 188)
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Font.Size = 11
    End With

    With ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)
        .Value = "Nb cars left"
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Font.Size = 11
    End With

    With ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0)
        .Value = "Price"
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Interior.Color = RGB(252, 213, 180)
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        .Font.Size = 11
    End With
```

Somewhere else :

```vb
    Worksheets(RealDataReg).Activate
    With Worksheets(RealDataReg).Range(Split(Cells(1, PosStartColumn).Address, "$")(1) & PosStartLine + (TPICode * 3) - 3 & ":" & _
    Split(Cells(1, PosStartColumn + 61).Address, "$")(1) & PosStartLine + (TPICode * 3) - 3)
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Interior.Color = RGB(235, 241, 222)
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Font.Size = 11
    End With

    With Worksheets(RealDataReg).Range(Split(Cells(1, PosStartColumn).Address, "$")(1) & PosStartLine + (TPICode * 3) - 2 & ":" & _
    Split(Cells(1, PosStartColumn + 61).Address, "$")(1) & PosStartLine + (TPICode * 3) - 2)
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Interior.Color = RGB(242, 242, 242)
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Font.Size = 11
    End With

    With Worksheets(RealDataReg).Range(Split(Cells(1, PosStartColumn).Address, "$")(1) & PosStartLine + (TPICode * 3) - 1 & ":" & _
    Split(Cells(1, PosStartColumn + 61).Address, "$")(1) & PosStartLine + (TPICode * 3) - 1)
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Interior.Color = RGB(253, 233, 217)
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Font.Size = 11
    End With

'Putting the calculation in the last cell of the table
    With Worksheets(RealDataReg)
            .Cells(PosStartLine + (TPICode * 3) - 3, PosStartColumn + 61).Formula = "=SUM(" & _
            .Cells(PosStartLine + (TPICode * 3) - 3, PosStartColumn + 1).Address(False, False) & ":" & _
            .Cells(PosStartLine + (TPICode * 3) - 3, Split(Cells(1, PosStartColumn + 60).Address, "$")(1)).Address(False, False) & ")"
    End With
'Formatting the cells with the calculations
    With Worksheets(RealDataReg).Range(Split(Cells(1, PosStartColumn + 61).Address, "$")(1) & PosStartLine + (TPICode * 3) - 3)
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Interior.Color = RGB(216, 228, 188)
            .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Font.Size = 11
            .Select
    End With
```

And so on, and so on...

Do someone know a clever way to make all this formatting more efficient.nicer?As you probably saw, the formatting is each time really similar, but small differences appear (colour, the borders, the ranges etc)

I thought about making a function that I'll call, but I'll have to give it all the same informations, so, I guess it's quite pointless...
As example, if I take this formatting block :

```vb
With Worksheets(RealDataReg).Range(Split(Cells(1, PosStartColumn).Address, "$")(1) & PosStartLine + (TPICode * 3) - 3 & ":" & _
Split(Cells(1, PosStartColumn + 61).Address, "$")(1) & PosStartLine + (TPICode * 3) - 3)
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Interior.Color = RGB(235, 241, 222)
    .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Font.Size = 11
End With
```

It would become something like this :

```vb
Call FormatFunction( Worksheets(RealDataReg), Range(Split(Cells(1, PosStartColumn).Address, "$")(1) & PosStartLine + (TPICode * 3) - 3 & ":" & _
Split(Cells(1, PosStartColumn + 61).Address, "$")(1) & PosStartLine + (TPICode * 3) - 3), xlRight, xlCenter, (235, 241, 222), xlContinuous, 11))
```

But of course, there would be some parameters that are not needed in some cases, so I'll have to "aim for the good ones" when passing the parameters... It's easier to do it with the standard VBA formatting, I guess...

I imagine there is a standard clever way of doing this, but I was not able to find anything on google (it just gives me results on how to format the tables, but I already know that :D )

Thanks by advance !

Comment: "I thought about making a function that I'll call, but I'll have to give it all the same informations, so, I guess it's quite pointless..." that is not true. You will write the fromatting function just once and then call that function with the parameters you need. This is the way to go, less code, more efficiency

Comment: @Damian I edit my question to detail on this subject ;)

Comment: for "parameters not needed sometimes" you have the `Optional` before a parameter, makes it optional so you can give it or not.

Comment: Yes, but if I define my function as FormatFunction(optional HorizAlign, optional VertAlign, optional InterColour) and I want just to use the colour parameter, I have to write it either ```vbaFormatFunction( , , RGB(whatever))``` or ```FormatFunction( InterColour = RGB(whatever))``` ... To my eyes, both are less efficient than the standard VBA formatting :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe someone will prove me wrong (it'd be great if they did) but I don't believe there is any "right" answer to your question.

Perhaps the easiest and least redundant way forward would be start by identifying two or more formats that frequently appear together.  Then defining a custom data type to pass the formats with one variable.

Alternatively, you could create a subroutine that set those same formats and you pass the object being formatted as the parameter.  Though this is not something I would really recommend, too much work, to little benefit, and a bit messy.

Late edit: you can try adding a hidden template sheet to copy and paste formats instead of remaking them each time.

My personal choice is actually quite a bit more complicated, but I feel it is more elegant, and easier to both maintain and modify.  Long story short: constants and enumerators are stacked into datatypes used for categories that are set by a class.

For example, I have a button states, they can be: on, off, idle, or loading. Each state is substantially distinct from the other.  I start by defining all the possible base attributes as constants or enumerators(like color, font size, etc). Then I define an attribute datatype to hold them.  This datatype is applicable to every button (like back color, forecolor, etc)  I roll those datatypes up a level to another datatype that represents the specific state (on, off, etc).  I create a variable of that type for each state. The datatypes are populated when the application initializes and I use a class to bring it all together neatly.

All that work doing the setup isn't for nothing.   Any number of formats can be changed in a single line with no repetition while ensuring one change in one location apples to every object.  That allows for cleaner self documenting code that is easy to write and maintain while also baking uniformity into the objects throughout the project.

For example, when used as a property:

`myButton.State = isOn`

Or a method:

`SetButtonState myButton, isDisabled, "Not Available"`

Setting it up is not exactly trivial but it isn't hard and I think it's worth the effort.

Sidenote: I could have used classes instead if those datatypes, but I consider the class list valuable real estate in the project explorer and unworthy of such minutia.

Comment: Well, I was not speaking about buttons ^^, But I see your point... Gathering together the things that are repeated again and again, in only one instruction. That could make the things lighter, yes...

Comment: @zepeu Aye, not what you were speaking about, but still entirely relevant.  Equally applicable to a range, chart, worksheet, or just about any editable object.

Comment: Well, I see; this seems like a good way to do it, but in my case, for the 3 things that are static and repeated all along, I guess the standard solution is the best solution... It's really not efficient... Or I should do everything at once, all the cells having the same formatting at once, at the end... That looks like problems to come ^^, Thanks !

Comment: @zepeu another option to consider is a template sheet.  If you create a worksheet with different regions formatted the way you want then you can copy and paste the format where you need it.  You can also make the sheet `xlVeryHidden` so it's invisible to the user.

Comment: You mean, having a sort of hided template file, and, in VBA just doing a "copy - past" of the template instead of formatting each line? But I'm afraid, in my case, it will not be usefull as the file I build is a list, and the number of items (Files) in this list will increase... And if I'm right, if I do a template like you say, I have to format whole columns, and Excel will consider these as "filled columns", therefore creating a file of 100mo.... Right? It's not really efficient, but I'll keep the idea in mind for when I'll have tables with a fix format to generate :)

Comment: You most certainly do **not** have to apply formats to the whole column (they're are exceptions like `ColumnWidth`).  You **could** apply the format to each single cell as your list increases *but that is usually inefficient*.  Typically it is best to apply the format to a final range.  For example, if create a new list from A1 to A500 then you do not want to call the format function 500 times, instead, you call it once and **apply the format to the range A1:A500** I'll update my answer when I can take the time to demonstrate.